# Suddenly high ping

Tags: ping, packet-loss

Today i had an issue with my ping, usually i get around 80-100 ms on yahoo.com and in worst cases with hosts that are far from me i get max of 250ms. But today i just had a weird problem that my ping suddenly goes up to a range from 500 to 600 ms. This is really weird now the internet is really slow facebook and all other websites are too slow to browse and load.

I did a tracert though the ping goes high not from my ISP gateway but from another hop so what does this mean? here is example of ping and tracert

```
Pinging fd-fp3.wg1.b.yahoo.com [46.228.47.114] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 46.228.47.114: bytes=32 time=576ms TTL=47
Reply from 46.228.47.114: bytes=32 time=609ms TTL=47
Reply from 46.228.47.114: bytes=32 time=551ms TTL=47
Request timed out.
Reply from 46.228.47.114: bytes=32 time=563ms TTL=47
Reply from 46.228.47.114: bytes=32 time=557ms TTL=47
Reply from 46.228.47.114: bytes=32 time=590ms TTL=47
Reply from 46.228.47.114: bytes=32 time=604ms TTL=47
Reply from 46.228.47.114: bytes=32 time=583ms TTL=47
```

Tracing route to fd-fp3.wg1.b.yahoo.com [46.228.47.114]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

```
  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  router.asus.com [192.168.1.1]
  2     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  79.134.128.129
  3     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  172.16.0.1
  4     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  172.16.4.1
  5     2 ms     1 ms     2 ms  172.31.255.1
  6     2 ms     1 ms     1 ms  178.20.184.57
  7   506 ms   513 ms   501 ms  83.244.54.205
  8   487 ms   492 ms   497 ms  82.213.5.138
  9   471 ms     *      514 ms  xe-11-2-2.edge7.Frankfurt1.Level3.net [195.16.16
1.53]
 10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 11   534 ms   501 ms   560 ms  YAHOO-INC.edge5.Frankfurt1.Level3.net [195.16.16
0.54]
 12   527 ms   532 ms   513 ms  so-2-0-0.pat1.ams.yahoo.com [66.196.65.144]
 13   535 ms   561 ms   553 ms  ae-5.pat1.iry.yahoo.com [216.115.104.64]
 14   549 ms   529 ms   525 ms  ae-2.msr1.ir2.yahoo.com [66.196.65.157]
 15     *      516 ms   521 ms  xe-5-3-0.msr1.ir2.yahoo.com [217.146.185.163]
 16   503 ms   502 ms   493 ms  ir2.fp.vip.ir2.yahoo.com [46.228.47.114]

Trace complete.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understand that ICMP traffic (of which ping is part) can often be limited or dropped on the Internet. However, in most of these cases this will affect the processing of such traffic by the devices and not the forwarding of the traffic.

Looking at this specific output, there could be several options but I would suspect there is a possible problem between VTEL and PATEL. As an end user there is nothing you can do yourself to resolve this issue, leaving you two options:

1. Contact your ISP to inform them of the problem so they can look into it and hopefully fix it.
2. You can switch to a different ISP (if available) and hope they do not experience the same issue.

Comment: << ping can often be dropped on the Internet >> is wrong.  Why tell someone that?

Comment: I believe the quote should read "limited or dropped" for accuracy, and I go on in the next sentence to clarify this is mostly when such traffic needs to be processed rather than forwarded (maybe I should have dropped that for brevity?). Are you seriously going to say it isn't?  That ICMP isn't relegated to lower priority queues? Queues  which will be more likely to drop traffic when links are congested? That ICMP won't run up against rate limits where it will be dropped? If so, you must be connected to a different Internet than the majority of the world.

Comment: ping traffic is not dropped by the Internet

Comment: I didn't say "by the Internet" at any point, I said "on the Internet" which is different. Yes, to be more precise it is by devices that forward data while it is traversing them "on the Internet," but by your very own rules I should be dropping these details to make my answer more brief. Further, you didn't respond *at all* to my comments because you know you can't without making yourself look more foolish than you already are doing.

Answer (score -3):

A possible explanation is that ICMP (ping) packets destined to large providers equipment may not accurately reflect the condition of the underlying circuit(s).  Control plane policing (memory/processor priority) may be treating your ping packets with a very low priority in order to preserve their equipment's performance for higher priority traffic.

Comment: Control plane policing would account for high ping times to the device itself, not to traffic forwarded through the device to a different destination (which typically won't touch the control plane).

Comment: "Pinging fd-fp3.wg1.b.yahoo.com"  right?